# Index Match formula returning repeated values from the same criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to populate data from a master sheet to multiple other sheets using a certain criteria.

If for example the user has input a criteria of "Transition Initiative", all the respective row gets reflected into the criteria tab.

Please see screenshots below

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DgOn.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGjF8.png)
I used an index Match but it is repeating the value found for that same criteria over and over again.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong ? Master list is where I am pulling these data from

=IFERROR(INDEX('Master List'!$B:$S,MATCH("Transition Initiative",'Master List'!$F:$F,0),5),"")

- this is typed in my column G for reference as I only want to populate the respective data that falls under this criteria

Populated fields for other criteria are using this formula

=IFERROR(INDEX('Master List'!$B:$S,MATCH($G3,'Master List'!$F:$F,0),4),"")

Please help!

Comment: Why are you returning *Transition Initiative* from the Master List worksheet by asking for *Transition Initiative*? Do you simply want all of the *Transition Initiative* in column F?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you described the desired outcome. What do you want to see as the result? What logic leads to the result? Edit the question to provide these details, then post a comment to alert people who are following your question.

Comment: @jeeped yes, if someone keys in the activity for "Transition Initiative", all respective information in the same row as that will be reflected in that same tab

Comment: @FadhilahAfif,, you have pulled wrong string,,, since you are trying to get all values (multiple rows) has `Transition Initiative` (as criteria) in `Col F`,,, for that you need an `ARRAY (CSE)` formula, not one you are using !!

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE to retrieve the first, second, third, etc. matches.

```
'to get all of the 'Transition Initiative' listed in column F
=iferror(index('Master List'!f:f, aggregate(15, 7, row($1:$999)/('Master List'!$f:$f="Transition Initiative"), row(1:1))), "") 
'to get associated data from column E using G3 and subsequent rows 
=if(g3="", "", iferror(index('Master List'!b:m, aggregate(15, 7, row($1:$999)/('Master List'!$f:$f=g3), row(1:1)), 4), ""))
```

If the *Master List* has more than 999 rows, change `row($1:$999)` to suit.

[image]

BTW, there are other methods besides formulas that would be more efficient. Autofilter and Advanced filter come immediately to mind. SQL query is another. VBA could make the procedure automated.

Comment: Hi! this helped for aggregating the criteria, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Since you are trying to pull multiple row, so that your issue can be solved by using an ARRAY (CSE) formula.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put criteria in cell `F70`.

*Instead of using criteria better use cell reference for the criteria, makes the formula dynamic.*

- Formula in cell `F73` to pull associated data:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(MasterList!$A$73:$D$79, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(MasterList!$F$70,MasterList!$D$73:$D$79), ROW(MasterList!$A$73:$D$79)-MIN(ROW(MasterList!$A$73:$D$79))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

---

Formula in cell `K73` to pull only activity:

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(MasterList!$D$73:$D$79, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(MasterList!$F$70,MasterList!$D$73:$D$79), ROW(MasterList!$D$73:$D$79)-MIN(ROW(MasterList!$D$73:$D$79))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

---

- Combination of `INDEX & SMALL` returns value using row number.

`{1, False, False, 4, False, False, 7}`

*Where row 1, 4 & 7 holds matching data.*

- `COUNTIF`, match criteria array to row number.

`({1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7}, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7)`

*Where first part shown position of match value & second part shows total row number.*

**N.B.**

*Finish both formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, then fill across.*

*Adjust cell references & Sheet Name in the formula as needed.*